# Regex not returning string if theres another one

Tags: regex

Given this regex query string:

```
(?:<.*>)?(?:.*)?("|quot;)(.*)(\1)(?:.*)?(?:<.*>)?(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?(?:w{3})?plainview.io\/archives\/(\w+)(?:.*)?(?:<.*>)?
```

I need to be able to select

"minister, a loyal party member with black rimmed glasses told us. He's the best man for the job."

which I'm able to do from the following text:

```
<p>This is some text before, &quot;minister, a loyal party member with black rimmed glasses told us. He&#039;s the best man for the job.&quot; www.plainview.io/archives/SysteBvsl</a> and some text after</p>
```

but not from the following:

`<p>This is some text before, &quot;minister, a loyal party member with black rimmed glasses told us. He&#039;s the best man for the job.&quot; <a href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plainview.io%2Farchives%2FSysteBvsl&amp;h=ATPBq9DrC_xIokWhmxk7f3nyKGofYnM9zGt3mF-7bfMNNupsX0WSR4TdE6VmX6W9gd_1Rnby1nXfIfq3MzgOS2PKryxKu9z3yci0ZvomiLHvYbVSfuwg29Y1Z_R1LEKRDXO3sAOZ2dsMgQ&amp;enc=AZMnRgfaZaV-J1wtvqulToF-RxOlkhgY6kzmkLuXSv26a0waxI3nHsI1rXkl-ILjrXkcnwajsVFizefc27K5A_WlqpJrNQLKWSTnDSwIGHGHYvWDp1CWeBP8vbzcQZcnJHA-ka3LvpJIYIO7_YwPaEpKsT0I0nNewd0aHZYbPtHghob7_7a_fubIkIy5g3R7ExA&amp;s=1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\/\\/www.plainview.io\\/archives\\/SysteBvsl&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.referrer_log(this, &quot;http:\\/\\/www.plainview.io\\/archives\\/SysteBvsl&quot;, &quot;\\/si\\/ajax\\/l\\/render_linkshim_log\\/?u=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.plainview.io\\u00252Farchives\\u00252FSysteBvsl&amp;h=ATPBq9DrC_xIokWhmxk7f3nyKGofYnM9zGt3mF-7bfMNNupsX0WSR4TdE6VmX6W9gd_1Rnby1nXfIfq3MzgOS2PKryxKu9z3yci0ZvomiLHvYbVSfuwg29Y1Z_R1LEKRDXO3sAOZ2dsMgQ&amp;enc=AZMnRgfaZaV-J1wtvqulToF-RxOlkhgY6kzmkLuXSv26a0waxI3nHsI1rXkl-ILjrXkcnwajsVFizefc27K5A_WlqpJrNQLKWSTnDSwIGHGHYvWDp1CWeBP8vbzcQZcnJHA-ka3LvpJIYIO7_YwPaEpKsT0I0nNewd0aHZYbPtHghob7_7a_fubIkIy5g3R7ExA&amp;d&quot;);">www.plainview.io/archives/SysteBvsl</a> and some text after</p>`

Instead, for the latter, I get

```
\\/si\\/ajax\\/l\\/render_linkshim_log\\/?u=http\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fwww.plainview.io\\u00252Farchives\\u00252FSysteBvsl&amp;h=ATPBq9DrC_xIokWhmxk7f3nyKGofYnM9zGt3mF-7bfMNNupsX0WSR4TdE6VmX6W9gd_1Rnby1nXfIfq3MzgOS2PKryxKu9z3yci0ZvomiLHvYbVSfuwg29Y1Z_R1LEKRDXO3sAOZ2dsMgQ&amp;enc=AZMnRgfaZaV-J1wtvqulToF-RxOlkhgY6kzmkLuXSv26a0waxI3nHsI1rXkl-ILjrXkcnwajsVFizefc27K5A_WlqpJrNQLKWSTnDSwIGHGHYvWDp1CWeBP8vbzcQZcnJHA-ka3LvpJIYIO7_YwPaEpKsT0I0nNewd0aHZYbPtHghob7_7a_fubIkIy5g3R7ExA&amp;d&
```

Why is it that when I add more text (that is actually AFTER the string I need), it selects the one that comes after?

Comment: What function do you call? It seems that you call something that matches the whole string and returns the last seen match. Would be nice to know what language you are using

Comment: I'm testing this on http://www.regexr.com I'm simply looking at the capture groups for my results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about how regexes run internally.

Your problem here is mainly the (too) complex regex combined with *greediness*:

```
(?:<.*>)?(?:.*?)?("|quot;)(.*)(\1)(?:.*)?(?:<.*>)?(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?(?:w{3})?plainview.io\/archives\/(\w+)(?:.*)?(?:<.*>)?
```

will solve your Problem. What I did here, is just replace `(?:.*)` by `(?:.*?)` (adding a `?`).

A good resource I just found would be [Why Using the Greedy .* in Regular Expressions Is Almost Never What You Actually Want](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/03/why-using-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want)

A much simpler way to get the same result is this regex:

```
&quot;(.*?)&quot;
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it even simpler? I'm using it in a Chrome extension and it's causing all my pages to freeze. My intended use case is to search the entire HTML document for anything that matches: <optional_tag> quoted_text </optional_tag> <optional_tag> plainview_url </optionaltag>

Comment: Even simpler than `&quot;(.*?)&quot;`? I guess no. Everything that would tweak the regex performance will make it more complex